# Can I automatically sort tuple from one column in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I've put data on a posgresql table, and while running some query (not containing `ORDER BY` clause) I discovered that in the *Query plan* (outputed with `EXPLAIN`) that many time where used to sort tuple from column.

**Edition: Here is table schema**
There is two type of tables `class_tableX` and `prop_tableY`.
Here is how i build them and index over them.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "prop_tableY" (
    s VARCHAR(100), 
    p VARCHAR(100), 
    o VARCHAR(100), 
    PRIMARY KEY (s,p,o)
)                   

CREATE INDEX "index_prop_tableY" ON "prop_tableY" (s,p,o)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "class_tableX" (
    s VARCHAR(100), 
    o VARCHAR(100), 
    PRIMARY KEY (s,o)
)                   

CREATE INDEX "index_prop_tableX" ON "prop_tableY" (s,o)
```

**Edition: Here is the query**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT t2.p AS prop, t2.o AS obj, COUNT(t2.o) AS num 
FROM "class_Event" AS t1, (
      (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_sliceHasAnomaly")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventHasDuration")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_sliceHasEndEvent")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventPrecedeInCPU")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventFollowInTask")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_topObjectProperty")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventDetails")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_switchTo")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventIsExecutedOn")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_runningAction")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_anomalyHasSlice")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventPrecedeInTrace")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_sliceHasStartEvent")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventHasActiveDuration")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventFollowInTrace")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_runningTask")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventOrdering")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_domain")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_sliceHasFunctionality")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_traceContainsEvent")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventHasDurationFromPreviousOccurrence")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventPrecedeOccurrence")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventPrecedeinTask")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_switchFrom")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventEndAt")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_subPropertyOf")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventFollowOccurrence")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventFollowInCPU")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_subClassOf")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventHasDurationToNextOccurrence")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_requestComponent")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_eventStartAt")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_range")  
UNION (SELECT s,p,o FROM "prop_functionalityHasSlice") ) AS t2,  
"prop_runningTask" t3 
WHERE   t1.s = t2.s         
    AND t3.s = t2.s         
    AND t3.o LIKE '%ts_record0%' 
GROUP BY t2.p, t2.o 
HAVING (COUNT(t2.o) > 1)
```

[image]

So I wonder if its possible to automatically sort (once) tuples from a column of a table to avoid these sorts step during the query exexution ?

My understanding is that things can be sort before inserted in table. But in my case that is difficult to do because of privacy stuff. That is why i'm interested in a method implemented by postgres it self

Comment: You probably have no PKs/FKs and no seconday indexes. Also the bunch of appends indicates that you like UNION a lot. Please add the query and the table structures to your question.

Comment: As mentioned, please add the query and maybe some of the table definition (index or something you have). But in general: Putting something sorted into a table is only improving some things on kind of a random base -- you shouldn't consider this option in 99,9% of cases.

Comment: @wildplasser more details added.

Comment: Looks a little like you should have a look at the inheritance feature

Comment: @frlan what's inheritance feature? and what it is use for ?

Comment: Have a look into docu: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-inheritance.html -- I think very useful for databases with a huge number of tables looking very similar and you like to access maybe via one common table.

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY (s,p,o)` (three varchar columns ...) and `WHERE   t1.s = t2.s         
    AND t3.s = t2.s         
    AND t3.o LIKE '%ts_record0%'` : does not compute. And if the query made sense, `UNION ALL` would probably help a bit.

Comment: Looks like a sort-of-EAV-like schema, with each property in its own table, UNIONed together instead of `JOIN`ed. Have you looked into `hstore` or `json`?

Comment: @CraigRinger: could be. but an EAV schema would only need {E,A} in the primary key and would definitely benefit from integer keyfields. I also don't see the need for the H-striping, but I don't know the numbers involved.

Comment: @frlan Please link to the /current/ version of the docs not the /9.1/ or whatever version, it means we don't get lots of stale links accumulating.